# How to create a proxy for async api developed in .NET?

Tags: .net, mulesoft, anypoint-platform, asyncapi

My backend service is developed in .NET and it generates Async API specification and I could upload it to Anypoint platform Exchange easily. Is there any specific requirements to create a proxy for the backend service? Or will it be a simple HTTP pass through?

Have any worked on creating proxy for .NET backend service which is based on Async API in Anypoint Platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with REST APIs or Async APIs the backend technology should not be a factor, if they follow the standards.

If you are referring to the [Async API](https://www.asyncapi.com/) specifications, those are used to describe and document message-driven APIs, like message brokers. An HTTP proxy would only work for a REST API.

In any case [currently the support for Async APIs in Anypoint Platform](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/platform/event-driven-api#asyncapi-support-in-anypoint-platform) is limited to design and publishing the APIs specifications to Anypoint Exchange. Deploying proxies is not currently supported.